# Ubuntu not going in full screen mode in virtualbox after update

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu running on Virtualbox and I used GuestAddition.iso so that when I run the VM it opens in a full screen mode.
I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the old packages that were installed.

There has been no upgrade of the OS. It is still 12.04.

I successfully updated the packages but when I restarted my VM, I noticed that I again had gone back to its previous screen size and the guest additions ISO as also automatically unmounted. I remounted it but still Ubuntu would not resize itself.

What should I do?

Comment: "Certain installations"??  You need to be more specific - mainly, did you upgrade VirtualBox or Ubuntu?

Comment: @MartyFried Sorry for that, I have edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is still 12.04, you have probably upgraded the kernel version.

You will need to re-install the Virtualbox Guest Additions - mounting the additions disk is not enough (or needed after installation), it needs to be installed.

Comment: Yeah, my earlier version of Guest-additions was 4.3.10 after upgrade it was 4.3.20 and that is why this was happening.
I re-installed that and it started to function properly.
Thanks

Comment: I too was facing the same issue after running the update/upgrade and couldn't switch to fullscreen, Reinstalling the Guest Addons fixed it.!!!